# One-line piece of script to read a single row in a file as numpy.array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, readfile

Simple question, I have a file with N entries and M values. I need a one-line piece of script to read the first or any single row of the file as numpy.array.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` is probably what you are looking for, arguments to choose which rows can be found here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Forget the one line criteria (for now) and focus on two steps - loading the file, and selecting the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A=np.loadtxt('file_name',skiprows = N,max_rows =1)  #for rows
B=np.loadtxt('file_name',usecols=M)              #for colomns
```

Comment: But then you're loading all file in memory anyway.

Comment: I didn't realize you don't want to load the full matrix ,I edited the code